# Testing api using postman. But request is returning user name or email is invalid

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I created a user signin route from my nodejs backend server and I wanted to test the api but it's returning me with an error, though it's the error I put incase the code is not working as expected. But I cross check the code over and over again, and I can't seem to point where is wrong from the code. Please help by looking at the code may be am doing something wrong, that's why.

```
**userRouter path**

userRouter.post('/signin', expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if(user) {
        if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
            res.send({
                _id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
                token: generateToken(user),
            });
            return;
        }
    }
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid email or password verification' });
}))

export default userRouter;


  **User model path**

    import mongoose from 'mongoose';


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
    
},
{
    timestamps: true
}
);


const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


export default User;



 **server.js path...**

    import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import productRouter from './routers/productRouter.js';
import userRouter from './routers/userRouter.js';

dotenv.config()


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/e-commerce', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
});


app.use('/api/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/products', productRouter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Node server is Serve here');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(`serve at http://localhost/${port}`)
});

   **utils.js for generating jsonwebtoken**

   export const generateToken= (user) => {
    return jwt.signin({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    }, process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        {
            expiresIn: '30d',
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Express, res.send() is used for string and buffer objects. To send json data you need to use something else:
Instead of `res.send(jsondata)` use `res.json(jsondata)`

doc: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-res-json-function/

Comment: I try your method, but still go this...   "message": "jwt is not defined"

Comment: add import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

Comment: @Ahmad Salihu do you still have problems or does it work ?